# How can I create a simple debian package from binary?

Tags: application-development, packaging, debian, mono

I have been researching debian packaging, but I can't seem to figure out how to package a C# mono application made up of a single executable and a few resource files.

Can anyone help me figure out? All the guides seem to target source packaging.

Also, if there is anything specific to packaging mono apps please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We tried to write the easiest steps here in this blog post.

https://web.archive.org/web/20141210051522/http://developer.ubuntu.com/2012/02/how-to-prepare-a-compiled-application-for-ubuntu-software-center/

Comment: I already read that, and it seemed pretty good, however, dh_make didn't work, I got a long error message that suggested I go to the directory where the sources are.

Comment: Oh, never mind, I missed part of it, the directory name was in the wrong format.

Answer (score 3):

I think `equivs` is the easiest. You can install with:

```
sudo apt-get install equivs
```

With `equivs-control` command you can create a blank spec file and build your deb package with `equivs-build` command.

Answer (score 1):

I really like this tutorial, it sticks to just having to put a binary and a few config files into the package file:

http://www.hackgnar.com/2016/01/simple-deb-package-creation.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.