# How to Compile A Repo In Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, gnome-terminal, 18.10

It's a GitHub repo. I downloaded its source code and modified it. I know how to static compile it with cmake. but when I copy executable file to my another ubuntu machine and run it gives an error.

I know it is because of missing libraries or files.
So I need a way to pack all the lib files inside one executable file so that I can use it easily next time without compiling in all my Ubuntu machines

Repo link: https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/archive/v2.9.3.tar.gz

Please Help me and sorry for my bad English

Comment: It sounds like you want to package a binary into a .deb file: eg http://www.king-foo.com/2011/11/creating-debianubuntu-deb-packages/.

Comment: Yes, you are right,  but can you give more details about how to do it with above Repo? with xmrig. its written in C++

Comment: Maybe a dupe of https://askubuntu.com/questions/171796/how-can-i-create-a-simple-debian-package-from-binary

Comment: Can I use Windows OS to Pack .deb?

Comment: Do you realise @Eli Shain that xmrig has "tarballs" pre-compiled and ready to use for Ubuntu? You download from the [github](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/releases), untar `tar xvzf xmrig-2.9.4-xenial-x64.tar.gz` and then you'll have a folder, cd in to that and run the binary. Warning: doing this is running random binaries on your own machine, worth virus checking; don't run if you don't trust the source.

Comment: @pbhj Yes, xmrig has tarballs but its pre-compiled I need to change some lines in a file. so I need to compile it again after changes